# Treat getElementById return value as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I have a Javascript as follows;

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('someClass'))
{
obj = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
}
else if (document.getElementById('someId'))
{
obj = document.getElementById('someId');
}
```

Now there is a for loop which acts on this "obj"

```
for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++){
obj[i].addEventListener() // Pseudo code shown here
}
```

The issue is this works fine if `obj` is returned as an array i.e. from `document.getElementsByClassName`.

But if `document.getElementById('someId')` is true, it does not return an array and the for loop fails to execute.

How can I fix this issue, given that I cannot do anything to the HTML code itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create an array:

```
else if (document.getElementById('someId')) {
    obj = [document.getElementById('someId')]; // note the array literal
}
```

The return value of `getElementById` will *always* be a DOM element, so you cannot change that. IDs are supposed to be unique, so even if you have several elements with the same ID, it will return only one of them.

Given that `getElementsByClassName` does not exist in IE8 and below, you should also have a look at [`document.querySelectorAll` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) (which at least works in IE8).

Comment: Thx for your reply...Actually the above code needs to works only on ipad Safari...So is it fine if I use getElementsByClassName only for this browser ?

Answer (score 5):

Just replace

```
obj = document.getElementById('someId');
```

with

```
obj = [document.getElementById('someId')];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [];

if (document.getElementsByClassName('someClass'))
{
obj = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
}
else if (document.getElementById('someId'))
{
obj.push(document.getElementById('someId'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
obj = [];
obj.push(document.getElementById('someId'));
```