# oddity about createMediaElementSource()

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I was building an audio program and hit a stumbling block on the .createMediaElementSource method. I was able to solve the problem, but I do not quite know why the solution works.

In my HTML, I created an audio player: `<audio id="myAudio><source src="music.mp3"></audio>`

Now in my JS:

```
context = new AudioContext();
audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
audio.play();
```

doesn't work. The audio element loads, but doesn't play the song, nor is there audio.

However! This JS code works:

```
context = ...; //same as above
audio...;
source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio[0]);
audio.play();
```

All I changed was adding a [0] to the audio and the program suddenly works again. Since .getElementById doesn't return an array, I don't know why referring to audio as an array works, but just referring to audio does not.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757964/treat-getelementbyid-return-value-as-array

Comment: Which browser is this?

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle? There's something missing from the snippets you posted.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, `getElementById` can only return a single element as IDs are unique. Is this what you use in actual code (if not, did you check you didn't use one with plural form, or jQuery which returns a jQuery object)? Could you set up a fiddle for us?

Answer (score 5):

A few months late, but in case others stumble upon this and want an answer:

This behaviour is described in [the Web Audio API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#dfn-createMediaElementSource):

> #### The createMediaElementSource method
>
> Creates a MediaElementAudioSourceNode given an HTMLMediaElement. **As a consequence of calling this method, audio playback from the HTMLMediaElement will be re-routed into the processing graph of the AudioContext.**

Emphasis mine. Since the output from the audio element is now routed into the newly created `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` instance (instead of the original destination, usually your speakers), you need to route the output of the instance back to the original destination:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
var ctx = new AudioContext();

var src = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
src.connect(ctx.destination); // connect the output of the source to your speakers
audio.play();
```

The reason it worked when you added `[0]` is that `document.getElementById` doesn't return an array, or an element with a defined key of "0". As such, you might as well have written `ctx.createMediaElementSource(undefined)`, which doesn't re-route the audio from the `#myAudio` element.

Comment: Related bug report, still unresolved: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231656

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694697